# SQL - Calculate Incentive using Frequency (Mode)

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image: Student_Tutor_Incentives]

I’d like a SQL query to calculate the `incentive` column and based on the number of times a student was tutored in a month.

If the student was tutored in `AP Math` twice in a month then, the Tutor gets $20, else $0.

I don’t want group the date into month summary so, I’d like to leave the dates as is hence why I assigned $10 for each record where the students that were tutored twice in month.

Comment: Something like that? 'Select Tutor, sum(incentive) from Student_Tutor_Incentives group by StudentID, Tutor'

Comment: You know it is easy to copy-paste data from excel instead of posting a screenshot of data.

Comment: @Hello_my_dog_can_code - I'm looking to query the table.Student so that the output includes the 'Incentive" column as a calculated field. Columns A-E are columns in table.Student

Comment: @SalmanA - thanks for the tip, that would have been easier for sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just need window functions:

```
select t.*,
       (case when cnt = 2 then 10 else 0 end) as incentive
from (select t.*,
             count(*) over (partition by studentid, subject, tutor, year(studentvisitdate), month(studentvisitdate) as cnt
      from t
     ) t
```

Comment: Thank you much, I used this as the basis of my query and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

initializing the data

```
declare @StudentTable as table
(
    StudentVisitDate  date,
    StudentId int,
    StudentName varchar(100),
    [Subject] varchar (30),
    Tutor varchar(100),
    Incentive int
)

insert into @StudentTable
values
('2018-August-03',123,'Terry Brooks','AP Math','Shawn Green',10)
,('2018-August-04',123,'Terry Brooks','AP Science','Ted Berry',10)
,('2018-August-07',123,'Terry Brooks','Music','Shawn Green',10)
,('2018-September-03',123,'Terry Brooks','AP Math','Shawn Green',10)
,('2018-September-04',123,'Terry Brooks','AP Science','Ted Berry',10)
,('2018-September-07',123,'Terry Brooks','AP Math','Shawn Green',10)
```

getting the count of visits per month, grouping the data

```
;with temp as
(
select
StudentId,  Subject,    Tutor,Month(StudentVisitDate) [month]
,max(StudentVisitDate) maxdate -- the date on which the incentive will be calculated
,Count(StudentVisitDate) [count]
from @StudentTable
Group by
StudentId,  Subject,    Tutor,Month(StudentVisitDate)
)
```

getting the effective incentives for each month using the information from above table

```
select
s.StudentVisitDate  ,
s.StudentId ,
s.StudentName ,
s.[Subject] ,
s.Tutor ,
Case
when t.maxdate = s.StudentVisitDate -- the incentive will be applied on the maximum date
then
 s.Incentive*t.count
 else
 0
 end Incentive
from @StudentTable s
inner join temp t
on s.StudentId=t.StudentId
and s.Subject =t.Subject
and s.Tutor=t.Tutor
and Month(s.StudentVisitDate)=t.month
order by StudentVisitDate
```

Final output -

```
StudentVisitDate    StudentId   StudentName Subject Tutor   Incentive
2018-08-03  123 Terry Brooks    AP Math Shawn Green 10
2018-08-04  123 Terry Brooks    AP Science  Ted Berry   10
2018-08-07  123 Terry Brooks    Music   Shawn Green 10
2018-09-03  123 Terry Brooks    AP Math Shawn Green 0
2018-09-04  123 Terry Brooks    AP Science  Ted Berry   10
2018-09-07  123 Terry Brooks    AP Math Shawn Green 20
```